# SQL search returns boolean

Tags: mysql, sql, search, command, boolean

I need something like:

$variable = mysql_query("Search `name`='Jane' and if you find it return boolean")

Exists some SQL command for this?

I hope that my question is understandable. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,there is.

```
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT name FROM tableName WHERE name='Jane'");
```

This will return a boolean,so after that you can do something like

```
if ($query) {
    //do something
}
else {
    // do something else
}
```

Comment: No,mysqli_query is the correct one. However, there are some servers that don't recognize mysqli_query. If that is teh case then try mysql_query.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout  examples in php.net https://www.php.net/mysql_query

You can do

```
<?php 
/*** Some code here  and including , init connection to  database */
$variable = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  table WHERE  name='Jane' ");

if($variable && mysql_num_rows($variable) != 0 ) 
{
/** TO DO ... If you have result */ 
} else { 
/**  TO TO OTHER ... if you have no result **/
}
```

But if you use mysql_num_rows (which depricated) and  checkout for couting results different  than zero.
Also  you can  use  `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`  , you can  find more information about this and performance  here -> http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/08/28/to-sql_calc_found_rows-or-not-to-sql_calc_found_rows/